# Error Code: 1422. I am getting this error when using a trigger function. Already tried all the other solutions. Still no luck

Tags: mysql

Am I doing something wrong?
I have a table of student data named students of marks of all subjects:

[My Table Looks Like This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZl97.png)

Mysql Code that is giving the error is this:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER after_data_insert 
AFTER INSERT ON students FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE students  
    ADD COLUMN total DOUBLE(40,3) AFTER comp_marks ;
    UPDATE students SET total = math_marks+phy_marks+chem_marks+eng_marks+comp_marks ;
    ALTER TABLE students  
    ADD COLUMN CGPA DOUBLE(40,3) AFTER total ;
    UPDATE students SET CGPA = ((total/5)/80)*10 ;
END //
DELIMITER ;

Error Code: 1422. Explicit or implicit commit is not allowed in stored function or trigger.
```

Why am I getting this error?
If you can please share the solution.

Comment: It's entirely unclear why you would want to add a column *every single time data is inserted*.  The `update` I get but don't alter the table in a trigger.

Comment: A simpler solution for this would be to use [Generated Columns](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-generated-columns.html)

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I will take that into account as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the basic concepts of a relational database is that all rows of a table have the same columns. If you alter the table to add a column once, it changes all the rows, and any subsequent rows automatically have the new column. You don't need to add the column every time you insert a new row. Just alter the table once, and not in a trigger.

It looks like you want to calculate a `total` and `cgpa` for the respective student as you insert it. You could do it with a trigger this way:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER after_data_insert 
BEFORE INSERT ON students FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    SET NEW.total = NEW.math_marks+NEW.phy_marks+NEW.chem_marks+NEW.eng_marks+NEW.comp_marks ;
    SET NEW.CGPA = ((NEW.total/5)/80)*10 ;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

You must use `BEFORE INSERT`, not `AFTER INSERT`. Changing values in the row being inserted is possible only in a before trigger.

Use `NEW.<column>` to reference the columns of the new row you are inserting. The applies both to setting the column and referencing other columns in the expression that calculates the total or cgpa.

Comment: But I am using python for a school project and integrating mysql by using mysql.connector . And when I run the code it gives me this error :

Comment: mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER // CREATE TRIGGER after_data_insert BEFORE INSERT ON students FOR EACH' at line 1

Comment: Can you please tell me what's wrong.

Comment: DELIMITER is not necessary when using a programming API. It is necessary when using the MySQL client, because the client allows multiple statements separated by `;`, and that becomes ambiguous if the trigger body itself contains `;` characters. But when using a programming function like Python, it's not ambiguous because it executes the string as one SQL statement, regardless of whether it contains a `;`.

Comment: Therefore the DELIMITER command is only recognized by the MySQL client, not by programming APIs. DELIMITER is one of the client builtin commands, documented here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-commands.html

Comment: Are you trying to create the trigger every time you insert a row? You don't need to do that. Just create the trigger once. It stays in your database and executes automatically when you insert.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. It worked out pretty well for me and the teacher also praised me for using trigger and understanding it as well, since most of the students in our class weren't able to do that. Thanks.